# How to make arrays work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to decrease or increase the value in a textbox using javascript.
I made it work, when not using any arrays on it. 
If you're asking why I need arrays on this one. Its because I'm gonna need to integrate it later on a bigger project which heavily needs array on it. I'm a beginner in javascript, so I don't really know what are the requirements in making this work when making use of arrays.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function blabla(){
        var a= document.x.qty[].value;
        var b=document.x.qty2[].value;
        var pa=parseInt(a);
        var plusqty= pa + 1;
        var txt = plusqty;
        var tbox = document.getElementById('qty');
        if (tbox)
        {
            tbox.value = txt;
        }

    }

    function lastog(){
        var a= document.x.qty.value;
        var b=document.x.qty2.value;
        var pa=parseInt(a);
        var plusqty= pa - 1;
        var txt = plusqty;
        var tbox = document.getElementById('qty');
        if (tbox)
        {
            tbox.value = txt;
        }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="x">
    number 1<input type="text" id="qty" name="qty[]" value=""><br/>
    number 2<input type="text" id="qty2" name="qty2" value=""><br/>
    number 3<input type="text" id="qty3" name="qty3" value=""><br/>
    <a href=""><img src="add-icon.png" onmouseover="blabla();"></img></a>
    <a href=""><img src="delete-icon.png" onmouseover="lastog();"></img></a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried iterating through it using the usual for loop, but I cant make it work:

```
function blabla(){
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        var a= document.x.qty[].value;
        var b=document.x.qty2[].value;
        var pa=parseInt(a);
        var plusqty= pa + 1;
        var txt = plusqty;
        var tbox = document.getElementById('qty');
        if (tbox)
        {
            tbox.value = txt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work that way at all... use `document.getElementById('qty')` instead of `document.x.qty[]`, etc. for starters.

Comment: To label a form input, use the [`<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9) element. `<br/>` isn't [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); you should use CSS if you want each input on a separate line. Read ["Fancy Form Design"](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css), ["Label Placement & 1ayr vs. 2ary Actions"](http://locus.forestninja.net/2009/02/13/designing-web-forms-label-placement-primary-vs-secondary-actions/),  ["Web App. Form Design"](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html) for more.

Comment: thanks for the links, I'm gonna need it later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access a property worth special characters in the name, like this:

```
var a = document.x["qty[]"].value;
var b = document.x["qty2[]"].value;
```

Though, if they have IDs, it's much easier to do:

```
var a = document.getElementById("qty").value;
```

Or for example looping through all with that name:

```
var qtyElements = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
for(var i=0; i<qtyElements.length; i++) {
  alert(qtyElements[i].value);
}
```

Comment: there isn't any need to include the index # if I used id?

Comment: @Ieyasu - An `id` should only be used **once** in a document, a `name` can be used multiples times.  No, there's no way to use an index because `document.getElementById()` returns a single element...because that id should be used only once.